# Dynamic Group By clause in linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq

The following linq query groups people in a city by their professions.

However the only way I've been able to get it to work is to hardcode the cities.

Each Person has a City.  How can I modify the below query so that it groups by all the distinct cities that are returned in my query?

```
profession = people
    .GroupBy(p => p.Profession).
    Select(group =>
    new
    {
        name = group.Key,
        data =
        new List<int>()
        {
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Adelaide"),
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Brisbane"),
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Canberra"),
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Darwin"),                            
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Melbourne"),                            
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Perth"),
            group.Count(p => p.City == "Sydney"),
        },
    })
```

Ie, if my data set was:

```
Person {id:1, city: "Paris" }
Person {id:2, city: "Paris" }
Person {id:3, city: "London" }
```

Then the resulting query would be:

```
    profession = people
        .GroupBy(p => p.Profession).
        Select(group =>
        new
        {
            name = group.Key,
            data =
            new List<int>()
            {
                group.Count(p => p.City == "Paris"),
                group.Count(p => p.City == "London"),

            },
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yields the same output as your hardcoded list, but I'm not sure if it's what you want (hint: giving us your expected output will help a lot in that regard).

It simply creates a distinct list of the cities, then builds a predicate [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) that counts the occurrence of each city, and adds that predicate to a list. When the actual grouping is performed, each predicate in the list is invoked with the result of the grouping.

The notation `Func<IGrouping<string, Person>, int>` simply says "this is a delegate that takes an `IGrouping<string, Person>` object (the result of calling `GroupBy`) and returns an `int` (the result of calling `Count`)".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person(1, "Paris", "carpenter"),
            new Person(2, "Paris", "bricklayer"),
            new Person(3, "London", "video game critic"),
        };

        var distinctCities = people.Select(p => p.City).Distinct();
        var groupPredicates = new List<Func<IGrouping<string, Person>, int>>();

        foreach (var city in distinctCities)
        {
            groupPredicates.Add(g => g.Count(p => p.City == city));
        }

        var professions = people
            .GroupBy(p => p.Profession)
            .Select(g =>
            new
            {
                name = g.Key,
                data = groupPredicates.Select(gp => gp(g)),
            });

        foreach (var profession in professions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(profession.name + " =>");

            foreach (var count in profession.data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    " + count);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

struct Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }

    public Person(int id, string city, string profession)
    {
        Id = id;
        City = city;
        Profession = profession;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobbieMills I'm glad it helped you, and I urge you to understand delegates if you do not already - they are incredibly useful constructs on their own, but some of the strongest features of C# like LINQ and expression trees are made even more powerful when you utilise them with delegates.